# Access localhost wampserver via android device

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i access my localhost from my android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

I'm trying to access my wampserver setup wtih a connected phone or tablet to my dev machine. Using the emulator and 10.0.2.2 as the url location, I can access it.

I've checked local ip to try and connect with that, but it doesn't seem to bring back the data from the database.

For example,on my login form, connecting to the database, I'd use guest as username and password, and it works fine on the emulator, but on the tablet, I just get invalid login (the else statement) when changing IP to 192.168.1.x (my local IP taken from ipconfig)

The dev machine is connected to the router via wire, whereas the tablet is connected wirelessly if that makes a difference.

Ok, the problem was that I hadn't set wampserver to be online, and in the config file for php, I had to allow the ip address. That fixed it